# get html from froala editor v3 outside of initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, get, froala

I have a page that dynamically creates multiple Froala v3.1 editors.
They each look like this:

```
<div class="pBlock">
  <!-- other DIVs -->
  <div class="centerBlock">this is the editor</div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the html content of each one in a loop.

```
$(".pBlock").each(function(){
   var target=$(this).find(".centerBlock");
   var html=$(target).froalaEditor.html.get();
});
```

But I get

***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'html' of undefined***

The only examples I can find are ones where you get the html content during the initialization of the editor, like this :

```
<script>
  let editor = new FroalaEditor('div#froala-editor', {}, function () {
    console.log(editor.html.get())
  });
</script>
```

But doesn't that create another instance? 
How can I get the html out of the editor, even when out of scope from init?

I am initializing the editor this way:

```
// init a froala instance
function initFroala( selector , fWidth, htmlSet ){

        var tkn=getToken();
        new FroalaEditor(selector,{     
              key: froalaKey,
            attribution: false,
            width: fWidth,
            heightMin :200,
            heightMax : 1000,
            imageUploadURL: "cgi/editorUpload.exe",
            imageAllowedTypes: ["jpg","png","jpeg"],
            imageMaxSize: 2 * 1024 * 1024,
            imageUploadParams: {"token": tkn},
            events: {
                "image.error": function(error,response){
                    if( error.code === 2 ||  error.code===4 ) {
                        var json=JSON.parse(response);                      
                        console.log("%c"+json,"color:orange;");+
                      console.log("%c"+response,"color:orange;");+
                        console.log("%c"+error,"color:orange;");+
                        alertify.error( json.error );
                    }else{
                        console.log( error );
                        console.log( response );                        
                        alertify.error( error.message );
                    }

                }   
            }   
        },function(){
            this.html.set(htmlSet);
        }); 
}
```

Comment: How are you initializing these editors?

Comment: I added it to the bottom of my op, thanks

Comment: So returning the `new FroalaEditor` from your function and storing that would help. Then you should be able to used that stored instance to get the current html for that instance. Are you looping over the dom and calling that function for each element instance in dom?

Comment: Yes, I'm calling the same initFroala function for each instance

Comment: so I should store the instance instead of targeting it by ID or something?

Comment: That's what I would do...can use jQuery data() to store it on some element. Never used that editor so sorry about not being more specific

Comment: When I call initFroala, the "selector" variable is a unique ID, like #cb1, #cb2, #cb(n) etc

Comment: Use those id's to store the instances either in a Map object or on elements themselves. Then it's just a matter of figuring out which ID is in the particular `pBlock` instance. Seeing the loop used for calling `initFroala()` would help

Comment: I added the instance to the data of the element AND IT WORKED.
Thanks! 
I will add and update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered the same problem. "froala_editor.min.js" was unable to load fully when this instance was created and called.

Use below code that makes use of jQuery getScript() function:

```
var editor=$.getScript("/"+contextName+"/froala_editor_3.1.1/js/froala_editor.min.js", function () { $( 'div#textEditor').froalaEditor('html.get').text(); });
```

Remember to change the relative directory path to required js.

Answer (score 0):

the fix ( thanks to [charlietfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl) ) was to add the element object to the data property of the html html element

```
// init a froala instance
function initFroala( selector , fWidth, htmlSet  ){
        
        var tkn=getToken();
        let editor=new FroalaEditor(selector,{      
              key: froalaKey,
            attribution: false,
            width: fWidth,
            heightMin :200,
            heightMax : 1000,
            imageUploadURL: "cgi/editorUpload.exe",
            imageAllowedTypes: ["jpg","png","jpeg"],
            imageMaxSize: 2 * 1024 * 1024,
            imageUploadParams: {"token": tkn},
            events: {
                "image.error": function(error,response){
                    if( error.code === 2 ||  error.code===4 ) {
                        var json=JSON.parse(response);                      
                        console.log("%c"+json,"color:orange;");+
                      console.log("%c"+response,"color:orange;");+
                        console.log("%c"+error,"color:orange;");+
                        alertify.error( json.error );
                    }else{
                        console.log( error );
                        console.log( response );                        
                        alertify.error( error.message );
                    }

                }   
            }   
        },function(){
            this.html.set(htmlSet);             
            $(selector).data("editor",editor);      
        }); 
}
```

then to get the html I retrieved the editor from data

```
// get content  
var blockContent="";
var content="";
var editor="";

$(".pBlock").each(function(){        
        editor=$(this).find(".centerBlock").data("editor");                             
        blockContent=editor.html.get();             
        content+="&centerData="+encodeURIComponent(blockContent);
});
```